# ChromeCast Smooth Streaming

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, smooth-streaming

I would like to create an application which streams an ism file.

I followed theese instructions and make the app works:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player

But the video is still appear in my screen too, I want to stream the video only at the TV with full screen mode.

Is there any way to modify this sample how I want?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I have to register my receiver application and device?

Comment: You need your own app id, which means you need to register your receiver (unless you use the default receiver, which is useful for a quick test but probably not what you want for production). As for devices, if you want to be able to test your receiver and app before "publishing" it, then you do need to add your devices to your registration. After your app is published, everyone can access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that the video plays both on your mobile device and on your TV and you only want it to be on your TV, then modify your mobile application to not play the movie on your phone. If You mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: I had to write more details about the issue, sorry.
I developing a Chrome application. 
For example, the sender contains a Button, and if the user clicks on that button, the receiver app will play a SmoothStreaming video.

Comment: Again, what happens on the sender (and receiver for that matter) is up to you; if you start casting, you can pause your local player, or hide the player, or do as you wish; it is not up to the SDK to decide or implement what you think is right for your app.